# cypress-mochawesome-reporter is not generating html reports

Tags: javascript, npm, cypress, report, ui-automation

my mochawesome reporter is not generating html reports when I created a separate function for **'setupNodeEvents'** before creating this function it was working fine, in image shared below you can see it is generating some json files but not generating html document of report, and i am using a package called **"cypress-mochawesome-reporter": "^3.3.0"**

cypress.config.js -

```
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const preprocessor = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor");
const browserify = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/browserify");

async function setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
  screenshotOnRunFailure = true;
  require("cypress-mochawesome-reporter/plugin")(on); // for html reports

  // This is required for the preprocessor to be able to generate JSON reports after each run, and more,
  await preprocessor.addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);
  on("file:preprocessor", browserify.default(config));

  // Make sure to return the config object as it might have been modified by the plugin.
  return config;
}

module.exports = defineConfig({
  reporter: "cypress-mochawesome-reporter", // for html reports
  env: {
    baseUrl: "https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/",
  },
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents,
    specPattern: "cypress/integration/Tests/*.js",
    // specPattern: "cypress/integration/Tests/BDD/*.feature",
    downloadsFolder: "cypress/downloads",
  },
});
```

[image]

Comment: To be curious, why don't you use the [HTML reports](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/docs/html-report.md) from `cypress-cucumber-preprocessor`?

Comment: yeah I can use that but now i am curious why is this thing not working and what's the solution for it